# In array (vector) of numbers find two numbers, product of which is the biggest. Using nested loops is forbiden

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, vector

I have vector `array`. 
user inputs some integer values in it. 
For instance vector `array` can be like this: 
`array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 333, 123, 534, 1, 3, 0, -12, -11]`  
How to find pair of numbers in this vector the product of which is the biggest? Do not use nested loops (loop in loop), it is forbidden. I don't need ready solution, i need just an idea. Thank you so much

Answer (score 4):

The best idea that comes to mind is to find the 2 largest positive and the 2 smallest negative numbers. One of those pairs has the largest product in the array.

This can be done in linear time and with just one pass. Have 2 variables `largest` and `second_largest` and initialize them to the smallest possible value. As you iterate over the array check whether the value is greater than `largest`. If so, put `largest` in `second_largest` and update `largest` to the new value. If the value is not greater than `largest` but greater than `second_largest`, update `second_largest`.

This same idea can be implemented for the 2 smallest negative values too.

At the end take whichever pair produces the largest product.

There is one edges that you need to take care of: The array has only 2 values and they have different signs or one of them is zero. Take care of this edge case by checking the array length and if it is 2, just return the product of those 2 values as you cannot do any better. This edge case can also be taken care of in the main algorithm, as pointed out by @apple-apple, but I wanted to make sure you are consciously aware of it.

Comment: I believe what you said already works for 2 value array.

Comment: Yes, you are right. It works, depending on the implementation details. I can imagine how one could create a bug though if they don't consider this case.